# dompdf - text on a single page / page_script doesnt work

Tags: php, dompdf

I'm using dompdf 0.7.0 and try to write down text in PHP on my pdf after rendering. I need text on specific pages and found the following from Answer from Brian
[DomPDF {PAGE_NUM} not on first page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193587/dompdf-page-num-not-on-first-page)

The function page_script sound like the correct answer. 
I could check if loop is currently on page 3 or whatever.

Does I have to enable any options for this function?

Example:

```
    $dompdf = new Dompdf( $options );
    $dompdf->set_option('default_font', 'open sans');
    $dompdf->set_option('fontHeightRatio', 1);
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4')


    $dompdf->set_option('enable_html5_parser', true);
    $dompdf->set_option('enable_php', true);

    $dompdf->loadHtml( $html );
    $dompdf->render();

    $canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
    $canvas->page_script('
    if ($PAGE_NUM > 1) {
        $current_page = $PAGE_NUM-1;
        $total_pages = $PAGE_COUNT-1;
        $canvas->text(0, 0, "$current_page / $total_pages", "open sans condensed", 10, array(0,0,0));
    }
   ');
```

It still be shown on my first page.

Comment: That looks ok, but can you add more of the dompdf-related code? Up to and including v0.7.0 you have to render the PDF before you can apply the page script.

Comment: hello Brian :) I updated my post with the dompdf initiation.

Comment: What is the value of `$PAGE_NUM` on each page?

Comment: well.. currently nothing i got following error:
 Notice: Undefined variable: canvas
when i enable php otherwise i get no output on pdf

Comment: Guess I should read the code better. `$canvas` isn't available from within the script, change that variable to `$pdf`.

Comment: The Variable is available before 
   {$canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();}

You mean i should try something like that:(?))

   { $pdf = $dompdf->get_canvas();}

Comment: @Brian Tank you. This worked for me: `$pdf->text(550, 2, "{$current_page} / {$total_pages}", "open sans condensed", 10, array(0,0,0));`

Comment: added an answer for good measure

Answer (score 2):

`$canvas` wouldn't be available from the page script as it is out of scope. The canvas object can be referenced inside your page script as `$pdf`.

Try the following `page_script` call instead:

```
$canvas->page_script('
  if ($PAGE_NUM > 1) {
    $current_page = $PAGE_NUM-1;
    $total_pages = $PAGE_COUNT-1;
    $font = $fontMetrics->getFont("open sans condensed", "normal"); // or bold, italic, or bold_italic
    $pdf->text(0, 0, "$current_page / $total_pages", $font, 10, array(0,0,0));
  }
};
```

There are a few variables available from within page scripts or embedded script:

- `$PAGE_NUM`: current page number
- `$PAGE_COUNT`: total number of pages
- `$pdf`: the canvas object
- `$fontMetrics`: an instance of the FontMetrics class

If you're using page text you have access to the following template variables:

- `{PAGE_NUM}`: current page number
- `{PAGE_COUNT}`: total number of pages

---

Note: Support for parsing embedded script or page scripts is disabled by default. Enable it with the following command: `$dompdf->set_option("isPhpEnabled", true);`. This must be done prior to calling `$dompdf->render();`.

Comment: Do you know how to style the `PAGE` variables ie. boldface as they are fed to `$pdf->text()`?

Comment: You would have to select the appropriate font with the `selectFont()` method (which I just realized I neglected to correct in that code, answer edited).

Comment: I guess I have to create three or so instances of `$pdf->text()` just so I can achieve this: "`Page of <strong>{PAGE_NUM}</strong> of <strong>{PAGE_COUNT}</strong>`" :-(
Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately that is the way you would do it at this time.